# Onclick event on modal with partial view is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I'm using ASP.NET Core, and I have a modal which is opened from Partial view like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" id="OpenModal">Create Lines</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="AgreeModal" tabindex="-1" data-url='@Url.Action("OpenModal","RequestApproval")' aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="ShowModal">
    </div>
</div>
```

The partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<RequestCreateLineViewModel>

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="testButton()">test</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test button function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function testButton() {
        console.log("here");
    }
})
```

But I don't know why when I click the button on the modal (testButton onclick event), it's always return testButton is not defined. TestButton function is a script in parent view.
Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: The **scope** of `testButton` is limited to the inside of the anonymous callback function inside `ready()`. You need to make it a top-level function. Also, **STOP USING JQUERY IT'S 2021 ARGGHGHHHH!!!**

Comment: How can I make it a top-level? I'm a fresher in ASP.NET, so I use JQuery, it's easy to use

Answer (score 0):

"**.ready()**" is a function to be executed when the DOM is fully loaded.

- In other words, **execute** the **required function** or method in it.
- For example：

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        test();
    });
function test() {
   alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You just need to modify your code like this:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("partialviewtest", "Test")",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ShowModal").html(data);
            $("#AgreeModal").modal("show");
        }
    });
    function testButton() {
        console.log("here");
    }
</script>
```

[image]